# how can we convert timezone in azure data factory to specified timezones

Tags: azure-data-factory

I want to write expression in a "Set Variable" activity and convert utcnow() to "IST" (Indian Standard Time"

I wrote the expression as : **@convertTimeZone(utcnow(),'UTC','Indian Standard Time')**

and I get the below error while I debug the pipeline:

**In the function 'convertTimeZone', the value provided for the time zone id 'Indian Standard Time' was not valid. '.**

I tried:

**@convertTimeZone(utcnow(),'UTC','Pacific Standard Time')**

and

**@convertTimeZone(utcnow(),'UTC','Eastern Standard Time')**
and the debug runs just fine for both of these

how to make it work for the cases where it doesn't ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no 'Indian Standard Time' in [Microsoft Time Zone Index Values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/ms912391(v=winembedded.11)), instead it is 'India Standard Time'.

So you should change your expression to this:`@convertTimeZone(utcnow(),'UTC','India Standard Time')`

---

**Update:**

> The name for the target time zone. For time zone names, see Microsoft
> Time Zone Index Values, but you might have to remove any punctuation
> from the time zone name.

When you use the time zone in Microsoft Time Zone Index Values, you need to remove any punctuation from the time zone name.

Comment: Thank you Steve.. worked like a charm..however it seems not all values from that Index list are accepted - I tried for @convertTimeZone(utcnow(),'UTC','S.E. Asia Standard Time') and this fails

Comment: @azuresnowflake1 You need to remove any punctuation from the time zone name. So this expression should be like this:`@convertTimeZone(utcnow(),'UTC','SE Asia Standard Time')`

Comment: @azuresnowflake1 If you think my answer helps you, you could mark it. Thanks a lot.